# How to erase path in arraylist by finger android

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw, erase

I have code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
 super.onDraw(canvas);
 if (DrawInfor.mDrawing != null) { //this is array path
        if (DrawInfor.mDrawing.size() > 0) {
           for (DrawingObject drawobj: DrawInfor.mDrawing) {
            canvas.drawPath(drawobj.getPath(), mPaint);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

When i choose erase, i set:

```
m_Paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
m_Paint.setStrokeWidth(30);
```

But it not work, canvas draw black lines

[image: screenshot]

What should i do? I can't remove the arraylist because i need it for many functions

Comment: Try to draw with intermediate bitmap, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36968919#c1